# BeginInvoke - Why isn't an InvalidOperationException exception caught by the catch block in this code when thrown by the method in the try block?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, delegates

```
private void f()
{
    Action<string> action = WriteLogToFile;
    AsyncCallback callBack = LogCallBack;

    action.BeginInvoke("Hello world!", callBack, action);
}

private void WriteLogToFile(string message)
{
    Monitor.Enter(locker);

    string formattedLog = Write(message);

    try
    {
        SendEmailNotifications(formattedLog);
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
    ...
    }

    Monitor.Exit(locker);
}

private static void LogCallBack(IAsyncResult r)
{
    if (r.IsCompleted)
    {
        ((Action<String>) r.AsyncState).EndInvoke(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which exception are you talking about? There is no apparent exception being thrown in the shown code.

Comment: Why is **what exception** not caught?

Comment: I don't think using `monitor` is such a good idea here: what if you get an exception other than `InvalidOperationException`? Better to use a `lock() { }` block instead.

Comment: You must *always* call EndInvoke() in the callback.  Remove the r.IsCompleted test.

Comment: check this link. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AsyncMethodInvocation.aspx .. check handle exception section.. may it will help to create some flexible way to implement this..

Comment: An 'InvalidOperationException' exception. Have edited the title. ;)

Comment: @Hans Yes OK. Just picked most of this code up from someone else. I've just added the email notification.

Comment: Your edit of the title hasn't clarified your question much...

Answer (score 0):

Is this a windows forms app?

Make sure your subscribed to the threadexception event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx

Comment: Its in a class project that used by a web app and two Windows services.

Comment: With your current code an exception would only be caught in the WriteLogToFile() method and would only catch the InvalidOperationException exception, try catching the basic Exception class instead. One other side note that's not directly related to your question but might be helpful: only exceptions that can be handled should be caught in a supporting library and unhandled exceptions should bubble up to the app using that lib.

Comment: Well it is being handled. Its supposed to write an entry to the log. This is the apt place for doing this as the code is running within the logger. Well it did finally run the catch block. I'm running it from a test project. Is my problem that the test is returning and the spawned threads are being cancelled before they've completed? I thought that calling EndInvoke would make the test run wait until all the spawned threads are complete.

Comment: @Ian: The function `f` returns instantaneous, because you just start an async action. When called by a unit testing framework it won't wait for spawned threads to complete. You have to do this yourself inside of `f` or the calling test function. The `EndInvoke` is executed not until the callback is called which is after the `WriteLogToFile` call is finished.

Comment: So what happens to those async threads which haven't finished when the test completes? Are they just stopped wherever they happen to be?